# Strange errors with asynchronous requests

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

```py
async def rss_downloader(rss):
    global counter
    async with download_limit:
        headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.79 Safari/537.36'
        }
        try:
            response = await httpx.get(rss, headers=headers, verify=False)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                r_text = response.text
                await downloaded_rss.put({'url': rss, 'feed': r_text})
            else:
                counter += 1
                print(f'№{counter} - {response.status_code} - {rss}')
        except (
            ConnectTimeout, ConnectionClosed
        ):
            not_found_rss.append(rss)
        except Exception:
            not_found_rss.append(rss)
            logging.exception(f'{rss}')


async def main():
    parser_task = asyncio.create_task(parser_queue())
    tasks = [
        asyncio.create_task(rss_downloader(item['url'])) for item in db[config['mongodb']['channels_collection']].find({'url': {'$ne': 'No RSS'}})
    ]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks, parser_task)
```

Very often, this code cannot load some pages, causing various errors. [Here is an example](https://pastebin.com/9UYC1mPf) of some errors.
But when I try to load the same pages one at a time, everything is fine:

```py
In [1]: import httpx

In [2]: r = await httpx.get('http://www.spinmob.com/nirvanictrance.xml')

In [3]: r
Out[3]: <Response [200 OK]>

In [4]:
```

As a semaphore, I set a limit of 20 workers, which is not so much, I tried less and less - all the same, these errors appear.
Why can this happen and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`httpx` documentation](https://www.encode.io/httpx/advanced/#timeout-fine-tuning) covers the `ReadTimeout` you are experiencing:

> HTTPX is careful to enforce timeouts everywhere by default.
> The default behavior is to raise a TimeoutException after 5 seconds
> of network inactivity.
> The **read timeout** specifies the maximum duration to wait for a chunk of data to be received (for example, a chunk of the response body). If HTTPX is unable to receive data within this time frame, a `ReadTimeout` exception is raised.

Try first disabling the timeout duration for reads (adapted from the example in the above link):

```py
timeout = httpx.Timeout(10.0, read_timeout=None)
response = await httpx.get(rss, headers=headers, verify=False, timeout=timeout)
```

And then experiment with different timeout durations to see what is reasonable for your use-case.

---

EDIT: the API has been updated, parameter name has been changed from `read_timeout` to `read`:

```py
timeout = httpx.Timeout(10.0, read=None)
```

Comment: This seems to work, but the httpx.exceptions.RedirectLoop error still remains. What can be done with her?

Comment: @kshnkvn that sounds like a problem with the server you are requesting from, because that comes from an infinite redirect loop being detected. catching it along with `ConnectTimeout` and `ConnectionClosed` would be best, because there's nothing you can do there

Comment: Can you take a look at some other errors? https://pastebin.com/7V5qba7J At the same time, as I wrote in the question, all these pages open normally when I do it manually, and I use the same libraries.

Comment: @kshnkvn Hmm.. not quite sure about those honestly. It probably is worth opening another question for those (also, including the plain `python` tag as well will get you more visibility)

Comment: It seems the api for this is now `timeout = httpx.Timeout(10.0, read=None)`. Note the missing `_timeout`